# what difference between binary search and depth first search

Tags: depth-first-search

Binary research executing usually cause memory leaking problem, although it is faster than linear search. 
These two search methods, depth first search and binary search, which is more adapted to search random numbers.

Comment: > usually cause memory leaking problem
How could you arrive at that conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

Depth first search is the answer here. Because of the nature of binary search, binary search cannot search random numbers (in trees or elsewhere), only sorted numbers. You see, in a stereotypical binary search the middle value is analyzed (or root of tree). If the target value is higher, then the second half of the search domain is chosen, if the number is lower, then the first half. The search is then performed recursively on whichever half is chosen. For this reason, binary search will not work at all on a randomly sorted list of values. I will not go into the specifics of DFS since this question is answered. I'm sure there is a good WIKI on it.

Answer (score 0):

Binary Search would not be the best option for sorting random numbers.

Binary search is a search algorithm finds an element by taking the value of the middle element or root node and compares every other value in the data structure to it. It must begin with a sorted data structure. If the other number is lower than the midpoint, the lower half of the data structure becomes the full structure and the midpoint is found on the lower half. If the other number is higher than the midpoint, then the same process is performed on the higher half of the data structure. This process is repeated until the value is found or the halves cross.

Depth-first search is a search and traversal algorithm that visits nodes in a tree or graph data structure down a path as far as it can go before backtracking. It uses a stack to keep track of all the adjacent nodes of the node being visited and then continues to visit all its neighbors until those have also been considered visited. After all the nodes on the path has been visited, the algorithm backtracks using the stack.

DFS would be the best option for searching random numbers because the prerequisite of Binary Search is for it to be sorted initially. If the numbers are not sorted, it defeats the purpose of the algorithm. DFS will be able to find a value in the structure of random numbers in O(V + E) time complexity.